# Python Threading on an array without repeating the same array object on different threads

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have an array containing 100 items, and i want to use 5 threads to print every 100 objects only once, without each thread printing an object that was already printed by another thread.

my_list = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]

how can i make 4 threads that will each print 2 objects in the correct order?

Comment: pls show us the code and attempt you have made so far.

Comment: If you partition the array to be printed out by different threads, you cannot guarantee that the order will be correct without proper synchronization methods (in which there would be no benefit of using threads).

Comment: @adamius i know that in this example, it is absolutely useless to use threads, but i just wanted an example of how it would be done so i can better understand how threading synchronization and keeping track of progress across multiple threads works

Thank you

Comment: @Djangooow if someone were to write such an example, it would be a useless example that you didn't write yourself and thus didn't really learn anything from, especially because there are thousands of examples out there already about use cases that actually make some sense. What are you hoping to write, what have you tried so far, what are you running into that prompted the question to begin with?